# LaTeX to html pages with interactive features

Tags: tex4ht, pandoc, html, interaction

My search has brought to several questions with a similar gist to mine, but I could not find a satisfying ansewr to my specific needs. In addition, these threads were quite old and maybe things have changed since then.

I am looking for a way to create interactive webpages that are based on tex code. These are meant to serve as interactive notes for a course, that also include problem sets to be answered on the webpage itself, and they need to have following properites and featuers:

1. Updating the html based on changes in the TeX file will be simple enough to afford frequent updates.
2. Hopefully it will not be someting that will require vast knowledge in html, if there is a set of LaTeX packages + TeX to html converters that can do the job, that would be great.

Features:

4. Requesting response to questions, referring those who got it wrong to a relevant explanation in the file, and allowing only those who got it right to move forward in the document.
5. Record users' answers and button clicks.
6. Some more complicated conditional branching of questions/progress through the document

These features are all available on Qualtrics, so if there is a solution that can be plugged in there, that would be super.

Thanks in advance to all responsders.

Comment: Hi, I am TeX4ht developer. I think it can solve your fist two requirements. What kind of surveys do you want to support? Do you need math support? Could you add some examples of questions you would use?

Comment: The general idea is to have problem sets in economic theory. I don't have example questions off-hand, but the question description would have to include mathematical symbols; these will be either open-ended question with plain text answers, or multiple choice uestions. To be clear this all has to be written and constantly updated in LaTeX by TAs who don't know html and then easily recompilable to html. The complexity is in the transition between questions - I would ideally like the respondents to be referred to texts explaining the question if they get it wrong.
Thanks in advance! @michal.h21